# How to open new session screen in termux

Tags: python, termux

How to open new session screen in termux with python code?
I created a program that requires a new session/screen
And how to run a certain script by automatically opening a new session in termux?

In "**script.py**"

```
os.system('python3 file.py')
```

If you use the code above, it will only run in the same session, But I want to run the file.py in a new session/screen , without stopping **script.py**

Answer (score 0):

With Windows cmd, the easiest way to do it is the start shell command. If the thing you start is any command-line program, including python, it will get a new cmd window. So, something like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('start /wait python3 file.py', shell=True)
```

make sure to include the full path for  **file.py** because the new terminal window will be running a new shell and therefore won't necessarily have your same working directory.

Comment: I get an error message
```/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sh: 1: start: not found```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read it correctly, I thought you meant the normal Windows terminal, I have never dealt with Termux on Android so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, i tried by deleting ```start /wait``` And it worked, But it doesn't work by opening a new session/screen